# "flat" vs. "apartment"

Tags: american-english, nouns, british-english, synonyms

*Oxford Advanced Learner’s Dictionary, 8th edition*

**Flat:**
noun. [ countable ]  ( BrE )  a set of rooms for living in, including a kitchen, usually on one floor of a building.

**Apartment：**
noun. ( especially NAmE )  a set of rooms for living in, usually on one floor of a building

Does that means *Flat* is used in BrE and *Apartment* is used in AmE? And is there any other difference for the two words when one uses it?

I feel that *flat* is used more widely, is that right?

Comment: No citations, so I won't post it as an answer, but your sentiment generally agrees with my experience with one caveat: I don't feel that "apartment" in the US has the connotation of a single floor.

Comment: In Minneapolis, "flats" appear on apartment building signs, I presume to market to a more urban, cosmopolitan audience.

Comment: @Ben Hocking: In fact, I live in a so-called "duplex apartment" in the US, which has two floors and a staircase.

Comment: Related: [What's the difference between a condo and an apartment?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26762/whats-the-difference-between-a-condo-and-an-apartment)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*Flat* is used in British English, and *apartment* is used in North American English. The exact meaning of the word *apartment* depends on where you live.

In large parts of Canada and in or near New York City, it is used for a residence in a multi-unit building; this meaning is the one given by OALD, and is a synonym of the British word *flat*.

In most of the rest of the U.S. and on the West Coast of Canada, the word *apartment* is reserved for a *rented* residence in a multi-unit building; if the residences in the building are individually owned, they are called *condos*.

As Ben Hocking says in his comment, an apartment doesn't have to be on just one story (although the majority of them are). But if you live in a multistory residence which doesn't have anything either above or below your unit, even though there are residences attached on both sides, this is more commonly called a *townhouse*. If there are just two residences in the same building, you have a *duplex.*

See also [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26762/whats-the-difference-between-a-condo-and-an-apartment).

Comment: *Flat* is used everywhere I've lived in the U.S. where there are multi-flat (two-flat, three-flat, etc.) apartments for lease.

Comment: @Robusto I'm not sure where you've lived in the U.S. but I've never heard of anyone referring to apartments as "flats". In which cities have you heard people talking about "flats"?

Comment: Ditto nohat.  I've never heard an American say flat, but the US is a big place with varied terminology.

Comment: @nohat: I'm from Chicago, and have lived at various places in the U.S. The usage is not to call an apartment a *flat* per se, but as I said to call a certain kind of apartment building, in which the residences occupy an entire floor, a 2-flat or a 3-flat. That kind of residence is not found in Southern California, I think, but that's one of the places I haven't lived.

Comment: @Robusto: In Boston, if I understand you right, 3-flats are called triple-deckers.

Comment: @Peter Shor: In a lot of places. It varies. I've heard both. But you don't hear "double-decker" at all. At least I haven't.

Comment: @Robust: I've never heard double-decker, and it sounds wrong. *Two-decker* sounds better; I can't say for sure I've heard it, but it's listed in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_house_types).

Comment: I have only heard the term "flat" in the U.S. to refer to the style of apartment; a "flat" is a single-level apartment, versus a "loft" which has an upper level (usually the apartment's main bedroom).

Comment: @Robusto - I've lived in Oklahoma, New Orleans, Philadelphia, and Orlando. The only time I've ever heard "flat" for `apartment` was when the speaker wasn't from the USA.

Comment: To continue to nail down the regional differences, we have the distinction between "apartment" and "condo" here on the Canadian West Coast too.

Comment: @Peter Shor, I've heard "double-decker" before but only in reference to two-floor buses.

Comment: @Ross: Looking on the Internet, *three-decker* and *triple-decker* seem to be used quite commonly for houses divided into three stories of apartments, but *two-deckers* and *double-deckers* seem to be mainly sandwiches, buses, and ships. For the Boston area, I would suspect the difference in usage may be because a lot of buildings were built specifically as triple-decker apartments, whereas relatively few were built specifically for two-decker apartments (although quite a number of houses have been converted into these).

Comment: @Ross: Thanks ... I'll change my answer re Canada.

Answer (score 16):

No, it's not that clear-cut.

Both words are used in the UK: a "flat" would generally be a fairly 'ordinary' residence that doesn't constitute the entire space within a building, whereas an "apartment" tends to imply a similar concept, but more luxurious. As I understand, "flat" is rarely used in the US.

Comment: Agreed. In the UK an *apartment* often means an up-market *flat*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - isn't that just a modern copying of AE usage to sound 'upmarket'?

Comment: Just to clarify: "flat" is distinctly British, and I've never heard an American say it (I'm from NY/NJ and went to college/have lots of family in New England).  In America, your apartment can be a crap hole and it would still be called an apartment.  Also, if the BrE usage is a modern way to sound upmarket, then I'll point out the French word "appartement".  I don't know about origins or anything...

Comment: @theidiotbox: I'm not sure whether the French *apartment* or the Italian *appartamento* came first. Anyway, it derives from *appartare*, eventually from Latin *partire* which means *to divide, to separate*.

Comment: @theidiotbox, @nico: Adding to the language list, Spanish "apartamento" means (in Spain) a small, often *too* small, apartment, whereas a nicer and larger apartment is called "piso". There's no upmarket connotation to "apartamento" at all; quite the opposite.

Comment: Re the origin: in principle it makes sense to assume that the word was first coined in Italian, given that that's the language that the verb existed in. Larousse assumes this origin, although their date of first attestation (1559) is suspiciously late (the word "appartement" seems to appear in the text of a French law from 1483). The word may also have been coined more or less simultaneously in both languages (just as happens with scientific words today: there are more or less 'automatic' translations of certain new coinings without the need for "borrowing" as such).

Comment: P.S. I think in Spanish, it's more obviously a "loanword" because of the ending "-ento" as opposed to "-iento" ("appartamiento" appears to have existed previously to mean "division", incidentally). Incidentally, it's not clear that "apartamento" was ever particularly common overall compared to "departamento".

Comment: @Martin Beckett: The British 'upmarket' associations for *apartment* may well owe much to the fact that US movies/tv invariably depict quite substantial accomodation under that name (as opposed to the pokey British equivalent in our 'kitchen sink dramas'). Though I personally get the association from swanky French *appartements* I've been in over the years.

Answer (score 8):

An answer based on British English:

There are several components to this: number of storeys; sole-use versus shared-use buildings; and the target market.

As the OALD says, **flats** tend to be flat -  i.e. on just one floor of a building. And they imply that they don't have sole use of the building - that there are other units in the same building; either other dwellings, a shop, offices, whatever.

If it's got more than one storey, but does not have sole use of the building, then it's a **maisonette**.

If a flat or maisonette is being sold/rented to an international market, it tends to get called an **apartment**, as that's better understood in International English.

If it's the sole use of a one-storey building (i.e. if the dwelling occupies the entire building), it's not a flat, it's a **bungalow**.

If it's the sole use of a building with more than one storey, then it's not a maisonette, it's a **house**. Bungalows are sometimes considered to be a subset of houses.

Comment: And if it's semi-attached, it's semi-detached !

Comment: Your descriptions of the different terminologies is mostly correct, but a maisonette has one more requirement (and I know this because I own one and the legal definition has been debated in legal tribunal hearings I've been involved with with my freeholder). A maisonette must have its own entrance to outside as opposed to a flat which has its own internal entrance, but shares a communal entrance to outside. In legislation, however, a maisonette is considered a flat for brevity.

Comment: @Neo So a maisonette would be a townhouse in American English?

Comment: @JAB Reading [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Townhouse), yes, but only where the townhouse is "stacked". Note EnergyNumbers' description that a maisonette "does not have sole use of the building".

Answer (score 0):

To confuse things further, apartment in BrE also means a room - for instance you could have a three apartment flat.