# Apartment building - flat building?

Tags: nouns, british-english, compounds

Does anyone in the UK say *flat building*? I live in the US, mind, so I have no clue. It sounds a bit funny saying that. Do they say *apartment building* instead, maybe? Or is there another word for a whole building of flats?

Comment: we call flats in india, not flat building.

Comment: you never hear "flat building". you hear "flats" or "block of flats".  Questions about this have been asked 100000s of times on the net and many times on here - just search.

Comment: Related:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33622/flat-vs-apartment

Comment: Related:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26762/difference-between-condo-and-apartment

Comment: @JoeBlow, I definitely did Google it and searched here in the first place. I didn't find specifically what I was looking for. I wouldn't have put this here if I didn't. And I was not asking for a difference between a flat and an apartment. Do not jump to conclusions. It's simply a question.

Comment: @JoeBlow, Josh, I think you might be being a bit unfair here. It is precisely because those types of questions and answers emphasise British English speakers' preference for *flat* over *apartment* that the OP is quite sensibly asking about its occurrence in this compound noun. The OP is obviously aware of the term *apartment building*, and want to know what we use instead or if we use the same term. It seems a perfectly reasonable follow-up from the well-known apartment/flat/condo usage question. None of the posts linked to provide the answer to this particular query.

Answer (score 11):

In the UK, you would probably say *a block of flats,* or -- especially in the case of public housing -- *a tower block* or *high-rise*, if it was more than about ten storeys tall.

If you perform Google image searches on those terms, you'll get a good idea of what they represent.

I've never heard an apartment building being referred to as a 'flat building'.

Comment: +1 _block of flats_ is specifically for free standing buildings designed for shared/communal housing. I'm not sure if there is a specific term for buildings which were normal houses that have now been converted into flats/bedsits.

Comment: Block of flats is a common definition, but far less common than apartment building and condo(minium) both in UK and US  according to google books.

Comment: @Josh61 - What you say you found in Google Books regarding the UK's usage of 'apartment building' and 'condo' -- the latter especially -- just doesn't square with my observations during my decades of being a native speaker of British English. I suspect that though most British people would understand 'apartment building', a great many would have no idea what a condo was.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, Erik, Frank, and Josh. This is my first time on the site, so this has been very helpful. Thank you! :)

Comment: @bridey - Glad to be able to help. (And I'm sure Josh and Frank would echo that  :)

Comment: @Josh61 _Condo_ is not a well used term in the UK, apartment building would be understood to mean a building containing flats, possibly that is the term for a building converted into flats. When _condo_ is used, I'd say it generally describes holiday rental/timeshare flats in high rise buildings abroad (outside the UK).

Comment: _Flat building_ no, _flatted building_ ... possibly, _flatted accomodation_ yes.

Comment: I entirely concur with Erik's answer above. Nonetheless, I have a compulsive urge to share with you the fact that although we don't have: - *flat buildings* ... over here, we do have: - *flat pack buildings* ... which are a kind of self-assembly type building. Strangely, until you actually put them up, they are, in fact, erm ...How should I put this? Erm... flat buildings.

Comment: @ErikKowal, Frank, yes, I'm never quite sure exactly what a condo should look like.

Comment: "Flat" and "block of flats" is the normal UK term. "Apartment" and "Apartment block" is understood because we watch American TV. "Condo" is pretty much unknown.

Answer (score -3):

As far as I know, an apartment is called a *flat* in the UK. And a building with flats is called a *building* or a *residential building.*

Comment: bridey, if you actually want the answer, this downvoted answer appears to be perfectly correct.

Comment: Joe Blow, no. It's not.